# unix commands to delete files in different folders

Tags: mac, unix

Homebrew has given me some warnings and told me to delete certain files from both /usr and /Library folders, which are getting in the way certain installs. Is there a way to remove these files from the root directory, or do I have to manually

```
Warning: libiconv files detected at a system prefix other than /usr
Homebrew doesn't provide a libiconv formula, and expects to link against
the system version in /usr. libiconv in other prefixes can cause
compile or link failure, especially if compiled with improper
architectures. OS X itself never installs anything to /usr/local so
it was either installed by a user or some other third party software.

tl;dr: delete these files:
    /usr/local/lib/libiconv.dylib
    /usr/local/include/iconv.h
```

It also told me to delete another file

```
Warning: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework detected
This can be picked up by CMake's build system and likely cause the build to
fail. You may need to move this file out of the way to compile CMake.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the absolute paths to the file to `rm`, like so:

```
rm /usr/local/lib/libiconv.dylib
rm /usr/local/include/iconv.h
```

These will work no matter what directory you're in.

To remove a directory, you use `rm -rf` instead of `rm`.

Comment: thanks, but what about the directory in the last part of the question-/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework. Rm doesn't remove the directory

Comment: Is that a directory? Your question implied it was a file.

Comment: your solution worked for the two files, but I found out the last part of the question referred to a directory after I tried your answer. Anyways, I now did rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework